# How to upload multiple images in summernote editor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, summernote

I am trying to upload multiple images at once in summernote editor. My single image upload code below is working. Can someone please guide on how to tweak this code to work for multiple image uploads.

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onImageUpload: function(image) {
      editor = $(this);
      uploadImageContent(image[0], editor);
    }
  }
});

function uploadImageContent(image, editor) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", image);
  //  data.append("contentid", <?=$content_id?>);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "fileupload.php",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    type: "post",
    success: function(url) {
      $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", url);
    }
  });
}
```